# Core Data entity not deleting

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

This should be simple but no matter how many ways I try it it won't work. I've inspected the SQLite store and can confirm that this entity is never deleted. Here is the code:

```
        NSArray *accs = [[Storage getInstance] getAllAccountsArrFromDb];
        for (Account *a in accs) {
            [a MR_deleteEntityInContext:a.managedObjectContext];
            [a.managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        }
```

I have an account I delete when a logout button is pressed but although this code is run the account remains in the database causing issues next time I login.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I also tried deleting from the default context and MR_context.

Comment: Presumably you checked that `accs` contains the object?

Comment: I checked the count of the array before the loop and after and it remains the same. The object isn't removed.

Comment: Deleting from the context does nothing to the array contents.

Comment: @Wain I know. I create the array from the database again once the deletion has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your loop (I don't recall, but the mic might be nilled out after the deletion) to:

```
NSArray *accs = [[Storage getInstance] getAllAccountsArrFromDb];

for (Account *a in accs) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = a.managedObjectContext;

    [a MR_deleteEntityInContext:moc];
    [moc MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
}
```

(ideally save in batches instead of after each deletion)

Comment: I get an ```EXC_BAD_ACCESS``` crash if there are multiple accounts. If there is a single account I don't get the crash but it doesn't delete. I have also tried utilising MagicalRecords ```truncateALL``` method to delete all objects in the entity and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Which suggests you're trying to delete something which has already been deleted / invalidated. Turn on zombies and use instruments to find out more information about the crash.

Comment: I'm using ARC so zombies won't work. I noticed I'm getting this error occasionally in the console: ```CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts. with userInfo (null)```

Comment: Using ARC isn't magical, it doesn't solve all memory issues and it doesn't rule out zombies...

Comment: I was under the impression enabling zombies didn't work when using ARC. I'll check it out now.